# A master's degree from IGNOU is eligible for a CSIR -NET qualification?

Tags: mathematics, masters, assistant-professor, india

If someone completes his master degree in mathematics from Indira Gandhi National Open University (IGNOU). Can he be eligible for a CSIR -NET application?

CSIR -NET is a necessary qualification for lectureship or junior research fellowship in india given by the Council of Scientific & Industrial Research (CSIR).

Comment: I think the answer is yes if the grades are above the common threshold; however I am really not an expert on this. You might get a better reception on you question if you were more detailed. Explain what ignou is and what the CSIR NET is. You can update your question via an [edit].

Comment: Besides the answer below, I found [this page](http://59.163.216.82:8080/jrf/online/uni.jsp) which says the university code of IGNOU is 099. You need to follow the link the answer below provided and then determine if you're eligible. For your information, I would suggest you to ask CSIR to get the official answer. Please do not count on what the strangers on Internet say. Instead, please follow what the authority says.

Comment: I follow CSIR -NET official page but can't find the link where can I ask question regarding eligibility.

Comment: [CSIR Contact Address](http://csirhrdg.res.in/contact_addre.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for the NET application can be found in the [CSIR homepage](http://csirhrdg.res.in). Take a look into the [main notification](http://csirhrdg.res.in/notification_main_dec2017.pdf) documentation.